# horizontal to vertical table transformation in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, crosstab

I have a page that dynamically builds forms input fields from a table allowing users to enter input into the form. Each input is a field in a _info table.

I would like report showing all of the entries of a user in one line. Each field entry is a row. So I need to take the vertical data and make it horizonal. There are many different forms with different configurations so must be dynamic. I’ve come across a lot of articles for cross-tab pivots but they only work for aggragates/sums.

The Registration_Info table has multiple entries for one form submission. I need to list these horazontal with each form_field.label as its fieldname for reporting.

Below is an example table layout:

```
FORM
——————————————
FORM_ID|FORM_NAME
500|“Custom Form 1″

FORM_FIELD
——————————————
FORM_FIELD_ID|FORM_ID|LABEL
1|500|“Field 1″
2|500|“Field 2″

REGISTRATION
——————————————
REG_ID|FORM_ID|USER_ID
23|500|45
24|500|98

REGISTRATION_INFO
——————————————
REG_ID|FORM_FIELD_ID|FIELD_VALUE
23|1|“My Name”
24|2|“My City”

Required Report Output:
REG_ID |Field 1 |Field 2 |FORM_ID |USER_ID
———————————————————————————————
23 |My Name |My City |500 |45
24 |Another Name |Another City |500 |98
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this will solve your needs:

**STATIC PIVOT**

```
create table #form
(
    form_id int,
    form_name varchar(50)
)
create table #form_field
(
    form_field_id int,
    form_id int,
    label varchar(50)
)
create table #registration
(
    reg_id int,
    form_id int,
    userid int
)
create table #registration_info
(
    reg_id int,
    form_field_id int,
    field_value varchar(50)
)

insert into #form values(500, 'Custom Form 1')
insert into #form_field values(1, 500, 'Field 1')
insert into #form_field values(2, 500, 'Field 2')
insert into #registration values(23, 500, 45)
insert into #registration values(24, 500, 98)
insert into #registration_info values(23, 1, 'My Name')
insert into #registration_info values(24, 2, 'My City')


select r.reg_id
    , IsNull(p.[Field 1], '') as Field1
    , IsNull(p.[Field 2], '') as Field2
    , r.form_id
    , r.userid
from 
(
    select ri.reg_id
        , ri.field_value
        , ff.form_id
        , ff.label
    from #registration_info ri
    inner join #form_field ff
        on ri.form_field_id = ff.form_field_id
) riff
pivot 
(
    max(field_value)
    for label in ([Field 1], [Field 2])
) p
JOIN #registration r
    on p.form_id = r.form_id
    AND p.reg_id = r.reg_id
```

Here is a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a44e9/1) with a working version.

**DYNAMIC PIVOT**
This version will get the list of the Field first and then pivot them.

```
create table form
(
    form_id int,
    form_name varchar(50)
)
create table form_field
(
    form_field_id int,
    form_id int,
    label varchar(50)
)
create table registration
(
    reg_id int,
    form_id int,
    userid int
)
create table registration_info
(
    reg_id int,
    form_field_id int,
    field_value varchar(50)
)

insert into form values(500, 'Custom Form 1')
insert into form_field values(1, 500, 'Field 1')
insert into form_field values(2, 500, 'Field 2')
insert into registration values(23, 500, 45)
insert into registration values(24, 500, 98)
insert into registration_info values(23, 1, 'My Name')
insert into registration_info values(24, 2, 'My City')

DECLARE @cols AS VARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS VARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.label) 
            FROM dbo.form_field c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT r.reg_id, ' + @cols + ', r.form_id, r.userid from 
            (
                select ri.reg_id
                    , ri.field_value
                    , ff.form_id
                    , ff.label
                from registration_info ri
                inner join form_field ff
                    on ri.form_field_id = ff.form_field_id
           ) riff
            pivot 
            (
                 max(field_value)
                for label in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p 
            JOIN registration r
                on p.form_id = r.form_id
                AND p.reg_id = r.reg_id'


execute(@query)
```

Comment: Probably need to make the end result dynamic sql because the number of pivot columns will be unknown. Loop through the fields for the specified form, then add in the pivot columns. Pivot is the way to go though for the generic solution.

Comment: @ulty4life You are probably correct, I updated my answer to include a dynamic SQL PIVOT.